# How to visualize bars for a single excel column in Tableau

Tags: data-analysis

My excel file contains a column where cells can include one of 2 values (let's say X or Y). I am trying to visualize the breakdown between them in bars - one representing X and the other representing Y.

I know this is simple, but I'm a beginner. Apologies in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this kind of data:

[image]

You just have to drag your Category in Columns, and ID to rows (right click it and select Measure --> Count), like this:

[image]